# How good are a typical settlement's inhabitants at healing themselves?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, healing, golarion

Assuming a typical settlement with around 500 inhabitants. Would they be able to easily heal most wounded person from accidents in no time or would it be more complicated?

From what I guess, in such a settlement there would be at least a few persons with a decent bonus in the skill Medicine (I'd say at least 20 with a +5 bonus) who could Treat Wounds with only minimal risks of making things worse, so even in the rare event where 5% of the population suddenly had a very bad accident it wouldn't take more than a few hour before everyone is fine again.

Did I miss something, or is Pathfinder 2's world that safe?

Comment: The Lost Omens Travel Guide is just about to release and might have answers for this! I don't have it yet :( (at least, from a narrative/lore perspective)

Comment: Can you explain how you got to your estimate of 20 people out of 500 having a +5 bonus to Medicine?

Comment: @thatgirldm to have a pessimistic estimation I assumed half the people were "useless" (young children, elderly...) and the remaining ones were good in at least one skill (so at least +5, since this is very easy to achieve) and one lore. There are 16 skills and 250/16 roughly equals 16. Then I figured I had been a bit too pessimistic in general and rounded it at 20. Anyway I think even rounding it down doesn't really change the conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assuming a typical settlement with around 500 inhabitants.

This is pretty low estimate for a typical settlement, less than half of the level 4 town Otari's ~1200 from the [settlement stat block](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1168) rules but more than the level 2 thorp Thornhearth's ~50 from the *Blood Lords* adventure path.

Based on this and the averages described under the [Earn an Income](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=560) game-mastery rules, this describes a small town, probably a level 3 settlement.

> Would they be able to easily heal most wounded person from accidents in no time or would it be more complicated?

As a small town there's no universal lore-wise expectation of a dedicated medical professional, but based on the rules for [hirelings](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=67) being represented as level 0 services there should be someone skilled with at least a +4 Medicine bonus in an average settlement of that size who's willing to be hired for something safe (to them) like [Treating Wounds](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=57).

Such a hireling could treat one person each 10 minutes, and could address Hit Point damage from accidents for quite a few folks with enough time.

However there are some limitations with this, chiefly that:

- Critically failing deals damage to the injured party and might outright kill them (1/20)
- They'd expect to be paid for their service and need a somewhat expensive set of healer's tools (5 sp/day, 5 gp once)
- This only addresses accidents dealing Hit Point damage  (Treat Wounds won't fix a lost arm or a disease).
- And this only works where the wounded party survives long enough to get treatment

For the same cost this hireling could [Treat Disease](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=55), but this only potentially supports a single individual for 8 hours of work (a typical day), and wouldn't really be viable if there was a larger outbreak or concurrent medical issues. It also doesn't directly remove the problem like Treat Wounds does, but instead gives a bonus for them to naturally fight off the illness.

Another thing to consider is that this is a setting with monsters and powerful villains capable of causing those "rare events where 5% of the population suddenly had a very bad accident", where a limited number of mildly proficient healers might not stick around to slowly patch everyone up or that the population might not survive the accident if it's so severe. Or that those few with medical proficiency might succumb to an accident and not be able to treat anyone.

Answer (score 8):

Yep, you're missing a couple of things - or more precisely, you're making several assumptions about injury treatment that wouldn't hold up for most commoner settlements:

1. To perform the Treat Wounds action, you need Healer's Tools, which cost 5gp. While you could argue that a village healer has spent years building up the kit, and/or inherited some/all of it from a predecessor, 5gp is still a *lot* of money. The [cost of living table](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=253) on page 294 of the CRB says "subsistence" living is 24gp/year, while "comfortable" living is 52gp/year. So a single set of healer's tools is somewhere between 10-25% of an average commoner's yearly cost of living. It's unlikely most settlements will have more than one, maybe two collective set(s) built up over a long time.
2. The Medicine check to successfully Treat Wounds is a DC 15, meaning a village healer with a +5 bonus has only slightly higher than a 50% chance of successfully treating a patient. They *also* have a 5% chance to critically fail, thus further injuring the patient - or killing them outright. (A crit fail does 1d8 of damage, and some low-level NPCs have as few as 8hp *before* whatever injury sent them to the healer.) While the healer could try again if they fail to heal a patient, first, they have to wait an hour in between attempts, and second, each attempt risks hurting the patient further.
3. Not all commoners are going to seek a healer for every injury. IRL, people frequently do things like walk around on a broken ankle, wrap a sawblade cut in kleenex and duct tape, or run a bad burn under cold water (all examples I have personally witnessed). They may not be able to afford the healer, or they don't have time to go, or they simply don't believe the healer can do anything for them which they can't do themselves.
4. Hit points aren't *just* a representation of physical injury. In the [hit points description](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=372) on page 459, the CRB notes that hit points represent "your health, **wherewithal, and heroic drive when you are in good health and rested**" *[emphasis mine]*. For a PC, the loss of hit points doesn't necessarly mean they've taken physical damage. It might mean they've lost some of their will to fight, or grown more exhausted/strained, or are otherwise [flagging](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/flagging) without actually being physically wounded.(*) In other words, hit points are an abstraction of the concept of "ability to fight". If this seems odd, consider that the only difference between a PC at 1 HP and one at max HP is that the PC with 1 HP will lose the "ability to fight" immediately upon taking damage. That PC isn't necessarily running around with untreated broken limbs or bleeding wounds or whatever - while the GM might make a contextual ruling or the player may choose to play it that way, under RAW the PC does not suffer any of the ill effects you would expect from someone with major untreated injuries. (That's what the Wounded condition is for, and per the CRB, [it doesn't apply to most NPCs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=372).) The point being, just as HP are an abstraction of a PC's ability to keep fighting, Treat Wounds is an abstraction of restoring that ability. So it doesn't strictly translate to a local village doctor being able to wipe away all physical injuries of other commoners.

(*)This is also part of how temp HP are explained in-universe. They represent a surge of willpower or determination which allow a PC to survive longer than she might otherwise.

5. If any random person with basic first-aid skill, some herbs, and no magic could instantly and completely fix any injury, no matter how severe, it would be happening in the real world already. Major injuries like [broken](https://www.habbaspilaw.com/long-term-effects-of-bone-fractures/) [or fractured](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9743747/) bones, [moderate to severe burns](https://burninjuryguide.com/burn-recovery/burn-complications/), and [open wounds](https://www.healthline.com/health/open-wound#complications) come with long-term complications, and a village healer with limited training and equipment can't simply erase injuries without those complications in Golarion any more than a highly trained doctor with top-of-the-line modern equipment can do so in real life. A village healer would be able to set a broken bone, treat a severe burn, or bind an open wound closed, but that isn't the same as making everyone instantly "fine" again. The patient still has to follow the same recovery path as real life, which is neither immediate nor perfect. This is why both hit points themselves, as well as the Treat Wounds action, are game abstractions: it keeps players and the game from getting bogged down by the real-life complications of serious injuries and their recoveries.

**Even if your estimate about the number of people with a +5 to Medicine in a typical small- to midsized settlement in Golarion is correct, there are a number of other factors which make it very difficult or impossible for those people to instantly, successfully, and completely heal their fellow villagers.**

Comment: I think I disagree with every single one of your points here, but for a different reason for each.
1) The average lvl 1 towny could easily make 2sp per day of work (https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=23). 5gp could be just the result of 25 days of work from an herbalist: nothing a community of hundreds of people would struggle with. I'd be like if modern towns could buy a full universal medical equipment for around 2000$: that's dirt cheap!

Comment: @AnneAunyme That does ignore the [Cost of Living](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=253) for that person, and that the "average towny" has a pretty good chance to only make 2 cp failing at such an equal-level job.

Comment: I mean the town can hire an herbalist for 25 days of work (or 50 if you want to assume they are a rather bad herbalist). Then this herbalist may spend this money for their daily expenses and to pay their taxes.

Comment: 2) +5 is just the baseline: I think there should often be better medics than that. Crit fails only deal 1d8 of damage so that's not enough to instantly kill anyone, only to bring them closer to death but then they can simply stabilize them and retry, To truly kill someone a medic has to crit fail enough times in a row to bring their target to Wounded 3, and then once more which will require 3 1s in a row. Meanwhile if they succeed only once the target gets completely healed of their wounded condition

Comment: @AnneAunyme That lvl1 towny only has a 50% chance of making that money per day; that also assumes there are people in the town who need healing who can afford that - probably not true for your typical subsistence settlement. Also, 1d8 of damage could easily kill commoners lvl 1 and below, esp assuming they're already down HP (else they wouldn't be seeing a healer). Eg, an adept only has 8hp max. And per the CRB, most creatures die at 0hp, so there's no chance to stabilize and retry if things do go poorly.

Comment: 3) The Wounded condition doesn't apply to NPCs... in combat, unless that's relevant actually. Even assuming it shouldn't be used for non-fighting NPCs, then what to use for them? I am not talking about someone being tired after a fight here, more like about someone who accidentally dropped a lump of red-hot iron on their foot.

Comment: NPCs die at 0hp, per the CRB - you don't use Wounded or anything else because they're just dead. And just like IRL, many people are more likely to simply bandage themselves and go about their day than try to seek out and pay for a healer.

Comment: If there was one potential healer for every 30 people or so and they could heal you by spending between 10 minutes and one hour and no costly component, then their service wouldn't cost that much. Not more than what you make in a day of work at least.

That part of the CRB sounds like it is supposed to be just about combat. Assuming it isn't would mean that if this was a settlement of evil people then they would only get the wounded condition (and not die immediately) because "enemies with special abilities that are likely to bring them back to the fight [...] can use these rules as well."

Comment: @thatgirldm, the question is if and how healing in a pf2 world is different, your sprained ankle is irrelevant

Comment: @András I disagree. The question is about non-magical healing via Treat Wounds. PF2e humans are pretty clearly intended to correspond to IRL humans at the baseline level, magic and other fantasy elements aside. If everything about how human bodies operate IRL is irrelevant to Golarion, then it is completely impossible to make *any* inferrences about how non-magical medicine, injury treatment, or, y'know, *anything* related to how the human(oid) body works.